# sql count() query for tables

Tags: sql, mysql

i have two tables

table1 fields

```
      fid,fname,fage
      a  ,abc  ,20
      b  ,bcv  ,21
      c  ,cyx  ,19
```

table2 fields

```
     rcno,fid,status
     1   ,a  ,ok
     2   ,c  ,ok
     3   ,a  ,ok
     4   ,b  ,ok
     5   ,a  ,ok
```

i want to display rectors like this

```
     fid from table1 , count(recno) from table 2 and fage from table1         

     fid,count(recno),fage
     a  ,3           ,20
     b  ,2           ,21
     c  ,1           ,19
```

i try many sql queries but got error

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SElECT t1.fid,
       COUNT(t2.fid),
       t1.fage
FROM   Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
       Table2 t2 ON t1.fid = t2.fid
GROUP BY t1.fid, t1.fage
```

Comment: True, sorry, did it in NotePad++ X-)